# The /etc directory appears empty when I try to access files using R

Tags: r, bash, shell, singularity-container

I have a bash script where I use singularity exec to run a program from inside the container. I want to call this script in R using the **system()** function. Everything works fine until Singularity needs to access a file named **singularity.conf** located in `/usr/local/etc/singularity`. The problem is that R cannot find the **singularity directory** in **/etc**, resulting in this error:
**"FATAL: While initializing: couldn't parse configuration file /usr/local/etc/singularity/singularity.conf: open /usr/local/etc/singularity/singularity.conf: no such file or directory."**

I have already checked in the terminal, and the **/etc** directory contains the **singularity directory**, which contains the singularity.conf file. I used the `chmod` command to grant all permissions to everyone regarding the singularity directory. Despite these actions, the problem persists. When I try to view the /etc directory with the `system("ls -alh /usr/local/etc")` function, it appears to be empty, so I cannot access the singularity directory in **/etc.**

Can somebody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: `/etc` ≠ `/usr/local/etc`! Furthermore, performing `chmod` on system files is generally a recipe for a bad time.